# How to set html properties of a newly added cell through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var table = document.getElementById("traTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(0);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = "<td><input type="/text/"size="/30/"/></td>";
</script>
```

I have the following code and what I am trying to do is, when the user clicks on the button which fires this script. I want to add a new cell to the table. However, i need the cell which is added to be an input text box type. Is innerHTML is the right thing to use here?

Comment: you may want to use antislashes "\" instead of slashes "/" in the string to escape the quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to specify the `<td>` tag in `cell2.innerHTML`, simply do:

```
cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' size='30'/>"
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("traTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' size='30'/>";
}
```

```html
<table id="traTable" border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>First cell</td>
    <td>Second cell</td>
    <td>Third cell</td>
  </tr>
</table><br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing there is adding a td (containing a textbox) to a td.

So the result of your code (assuming an otherwise empty table) will be:

```
<table id="traTable">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="30"/>
      </td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

which is clearly invalid due to the nested `<td>`s.

There is nothing ostensibly wrong with using innerHTML, but you have to set the value correctly. innerHTML overwrites what's *inside* the element, not the element itself.

```
cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="30"/>';
```

will get you the result you want (N.B. I also simplified your code to be more readable).

Demo:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("traTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

  cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="30"/></td>';
}

myFunction();
console.log(document.getElementById("traTable").outerHTML);
```

```css
table td { border: 1px solid blue; padding:5px; }
```

```html
<table id="traTable">
</table>
```